# Issue running iOS unit tests on command line (OCUnit + OCMock)

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit, ocmock

I'm trying to get unit tests to run in CI (Jenkins). I came across this [a article](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/04/17/xcode4-running-application-tests-from-the-command-line-in-ios/) online with some hacks to get tests running in command line. I tried it on an empty project with the default setup for unit tests and the instructions there work just fine, but when I try to do it on an existing project that has unit tests setup I'm getting a ambiguous error:

```
/bin/sh -c /Users/jzhwu/smule/magicpiano/build/MagicPiano.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MagicPianoTest.build/Script-7C0B24BE155310BE001AC942.sh
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:266: note: Started tests for architectures 'i386'
Run unit tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:273: note: Running tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
UIPasteboard - failed to launch pasteboardd. Make sure it's installed in UIKit.framework/Support
2012-05-11 15:10:39:247 MP-Debug[24398:17003] loading model magic
2012-05-11 15:10:39:250 MP-Debug[24398:17003] loading model magic-analytics
2012-05-11 15:10:39.264 MP-Debug[24398:17003] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0xa2c5ce0 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 2}, {
reason = "Failed to create file; code = 2";
}
2012-05-11 15:10:39.264 MP-Debug[24398:17003] Try deleting and reinstalling the app to fix this issue
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include: line 269: 24398 Abort trap: 6           "${TEST_HOST}" ${TEST_HOST_FLAGS} ${OTHER_TEST_FLAGS}
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:339: error: Test host '/Users/jzhwu/smule/magicpiano/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MP-Debug.app/MP-Debug' exited abnormally with code 134 (it may have crashed).



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" build/MagicPiano.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MagicPianoTest.build/Script-7C0B24BE155310BE001AC942.sh
(1 failure)
```

Ignore the resinstall app part. That's from app code. So this tells me that it crashed during runtime at some point. The unit tests run just fine within Xcode 4, I just can't get it to play nice with command line. If it is of any help I'm using OCUnit with OCMock. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same problem. Trying to run Cedar tests from command line and I get the same "Failed to create file; code =2" error

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a solution for this. I ended up changing the tests (previously application tests) into logical unit tests and they ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems recently with an Application I'm working on.  I inherited the codebase and it had no tests setup so I had to build those in.  I had tried using Apple's standard way of setting up the project according to their sample iPhoneTests project but it didn't work.  I switched to GHUnit and I was able to get it working way easier.  If you aren't too far along writing tests I would suggest switching.

The [docs](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_command_line.html) are really good and worked for me to run from command line and Jenkins.
In my app I have setup a second target for testing by duplicating the main target, adding GHUnitiOS.framework to the build and adding additional sources for my unit test classes.

I know that may not be the answer you're looking for but I hope it helps!